# Codeigniter URL Routing - Capture Everything for Tree Structure

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

OK, I think I am probably (hopefully) going to be told I am going about this in the wrong way.

Currently, if I go to root of CI web I call a function which reads a predefined location with `map_directory()`. I then iterate it out in a view as a simple directory listing.

I then want to click on one of these directories to see what's inside. When I do that I call a different controller function called `browse`.

So if I click on one link I go to

> www.mysite.com/dir1

(which is Routed to `www.mysite.com/controller/browse/$1` - where $1 in this instance = dir1).

Now I am presented with a dir listing of `dir1`. I have configured the links of the displayed listings to now go to:

> www.mysite.com/dir1/subdir1 etc.

What I want to do and this might be the bit where I am cheating/going wrong, is capture everything after

> www.mysite.com/

and pass it to

> www.mysite.com/controller/browser/$1

So example:

```
www.mysite.com/dir1/subdir1/ => www.mysite.com/controller/browse/"dir1/subdir1"
```

I know I can't have '"' in there, but that's the bit I am trying to pass to the map_directory() function...so it goes /.$var (where `$var would = $1 = "dir1/subdir1"`.

So far I have tried in CI Routes.php:

```
$route['(.+)$'] = 'controller/browse/$1';
$route['([a-zA-Z0-9\/]*)'] = 'controller/browse/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'controller/browse/$1';
```

...but they all only ever seem to capture "dir1" never anything beyond that.

I hope that makes sense to someone....

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the special [_remap()](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls) method in your controller to override the default routing behavior:

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    protected function browse($path)
    {
        // ... do something with $path here
    }

    public function _remap($method, $params = array())
    {
        if ($method === 'browse')
        {
            $params = implode('/', $params);
            return $this->browse($params);
        }
        elseif (method_exists($this, $method))
        {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
        }

        show_404();
    }
}
```